# How to install a Canon MP560 Printer on a BRAND NEW MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, canon

I am not technologically savvy, however, I'm not completely useless. I've spent too much time watching YouTube videos and asking Google ONE MORE TIME how to fix my problem and I'm done. I'm about the just throw my Canon MP560 into the parking lot outside my apartment and smash it to bits, while laughing and crying.

I've put the install disc into my computer. My MacBook Prof is as up to date as possible as I've done every update that's been available since I purchased it two months ago. I put the Canon installation disc into my computer. Everything is great! Until it decides halfway through the installation process that the "drivers" were unable to complete the installation. What does this even mean?! It tries to send me to the Canon website to trouble shoot but NOTHING on there is remotely helpful. I'm really hoping this can be an easy fix otherwise my Canon printer will no longer exist after today. Any help you could offer would be great!

Comment: Did you try http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MP_series/PIXMA_MP560.aspx?type=download&language=&os=OS%20X%20v10.10 ?

Comment: Usually osx downloads printer drivers all by itself, making al printers basically plug and play. is yours really not working?